# How to compile C code using old syntax with a modern compiler?

Tags: c, llvm

I'm on OS X using `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2`, and I'm trying to compile various programs from [this archive](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/AllGems.tar.gz), and in particular the classical FitCurves.c which fits a Bezier curve through an array of points.

http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/

Some void or int functions are defined without a return type, which generates warning.

```
ConcaveScan.c:149:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
compare_ind(u, v) int *u, *v; {return pt[*u].y <= pt[*v].y ? -1 : 1;}
```

I'm not really sure about this: there is an error

```
cc -g -Wno-implicit-int -Wreturn-type   -c -o AAPolyScan.o AAPolyScan.c
AAPolyScan.c:106:4: error: non-void function 'drawPolygon' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
return;                         /* (null polygon) */
```

As I understand it, it seems that the compiler thinks it's implicitely declared as a function returning an int, but the function returns void, causing an error. Does it make sense in C to `return` from a function that is declared to return an int ? I'm confused here..

How may I compile this nicely ? I doesn't necessarily fail to compile but the warnings are not very informative. It's written using an old syntax, and I know it.

Answer (score 5):

You can just disable that warning since you don't care about it:

```
-Wno-implicit-int
```

Also, are you sure you're using llvm-gcc?  When I made a test with your example, I had to add `-Wall` to get gcc to say:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c -o example.o example.c
example.c:8: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
```

But clang said:

```
$ clang -c -o example.o example.c
example.c:8:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
      [-Wimplicit-int]
compare_ind(u, v) int *u, *v; {return pt[*u].y <= pt[*v].y ? -1 : 1;}
^~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

without any flags at all, and that message more closely matches the warning in your question.  On my machine:

```
$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Good question. I started manually invoking it (i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2)  to compile a single file  then switched to the Makefile. I'll have a look

Comment: OK so the Makefile calls cc, which actually is clang.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `-ansi` option, which specifies compliance to the 1989 ANSI C standard (equivalent to the 1990 ISO C standard). That old standard permitted implicit `int` and old-style function definitions.

C99 dropped implicit `int` (but both C99 and C11 still, oddly, permit old-style function definitions).

The compiler thinks it's implicitly declared as a function returning an int because that's exactly what it is, either in pre-ANSI C or in pre-1999 ANSI/ISO c.

But even with `-ansi`, a compiler might still warn about a function defined to return `int` (either explicitly or implicitly) that doesn't return a value. In pre-ANSI C, there was no `void` type or keyword, and functions that don't return meaningful values were generally written without an explicit return type. Old compilers wouldn't warn about this common idiom. More modern ones, quite reasonably, do, because there are better ways to achieve the same result: define the function with `void` as its return type.

And the complaint about the `return;` statement is an error rather than a warning because, as of C99, a `return` with no expression in a non-`void` function, or a `return` with an expression in a `void` function, is actually illegal (a constraint violation). In C89/C90, a `return;` with no value in a non-void function is legal (but causes undefined behavior if the caller attempts to use the result).

The warning messages include the option used to enable them:

```
warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
...
error: non-void function 'drawPolygon' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
```

Reversing those options should inhibit the warnings. It's also a good idea to specify `-ansi` or `-std=c89`; gcc currently defaults to `gnu89`, but that could change in future releases.

```
cc -ansi -Wno-implicit-int -Wno-return-type ...
```

(This is based on my observations using gcc 4.7.2. I'm not entirely clear on the relationship between gcc and gcc-llvm, but they seem to take the same options.)

Comment: Even with -ansi, llvm complains that AAPolyScan.c:106:4: error: non-void function 'drawPolygon' should return a value. IIUC, llvm thinks it's an int function when it's actually a void function. Can it be compiled without changing the code ?

Comment: @Antoine: It's *not* actually a void function. In C89/C90, a function with no explicit result type is implicitly an `int` function. If it doesn't return a value, the behavior is well-defined *unless* the caller tries to use the result. The warning is a valid one, but it's not required by the language, and there may be an option to inhibit that particular warning.

Comment: What I meant is that the person who wrote this function is using it as if if was defined as void f() . He's just returning at some point, but llvm defines it a int f()

Comment: @Antoine: llvm defines it as an `int` function because that's what the language specifies -- even in pre-ANSI C (which didn't have the `void` type or keyword). See my updated answer.